# Salesforce Flows in Salesforce1 app

Tags: salesforce1-app, visual-workflow

We are considering the idea to use Visual Workflows (Flows) for a few business scenarios in our project. However, we have several users dependent on Ipad or other smart devices. We are not sure how well Flows would work on Salesforce1, is there any article/doc where we can get a conclusive idea. We can decide then to go ahead and create Visualforce component instead.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You need to [add the flow to a visualforce page](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=vpm_admin_add_flow_to_vfpage.htm&language=en_US) and [enable the page to work in Salesforce1](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_sf1_visualforce.htm&language=en_US). As long as you are ok with the **limited layout possibilities** of the screens, you can give flow a try.